# Bought a second hand retro polaroid but I think the lens is missing, how will this affect photos? (I know nothing at all about cameras)

Tags: lens, polaroid

So I bought a polaroid in a charity shop for £5 (I know absolutely nothing about cameras, and I mean NOTHING) but it doesn't have the plastic bit inside the main round bit- I think that's a lens? How drastically will this affect photos before I start buying film? Will the photos just come out white or unfocused?

[image: the camera]

Comment: Could you post pictures ? Do you know which model it is ? Basically, if a lens is missing, you will get unfocused pictures (unusable ones)

Comment: It's a "The Button Polaroid Land Camera" if that helps. I have no idea how the lens isn't in it... There's not even any broken pieces and I can't find any replacement parts... Reckon I should just buy a new one? @Olivier

Comment: @Brogan It would be really helpful if you could post a photo of the camera you bought. Or point out on an existing picture of the Button Land Camera what is missing. Now it's quite hard to see what the problem is.

Comment: Added the photo :) @BartArondson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the pictures and your description it seems that the lens (the spherical part in the middle) is missing.
Taking photos without the lens will not give you any sharp pictures, all you will see is some very blurry colours.

As Polaroid film is rather expensive I would not waste it to this partial camera, but would look for a fully functioning one.